# Which is the definition of va_list?

Tags: c

[image] or

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned int gp_offset;
   unsigned int fp_offset;
   void *overflow_arg_area;
   void *reg_save_area;
} va_list[1];
```

I see both of them when searching.

BTW,what does the `va_list[1]` mean?

Answer (score 3):

How va_list is defined is entirely up to your compiler, operating system and ABI. On some operating systems it can be defined by a struct or even a simple pointer to something, on others it is just internal compiler black magic that can't be expressed with a C struct.

Comment: What does `[1]` mean in the typedef?

Answer (score -1):

you can find all these on this

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/include/stdarg.h.htm

There you can notice when the definitions of the va_list is changing according to the environment.

You can also find some information on follows.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_list/